# handlebars template for data grid

Tags: json, handlebars.js

i have recently started using handlerbar.js in my projects and it seems quite interesting.So far so good, but im struggling in creating dynamic data grids using a template.

i have following json

```
grid : [
{
   question : 'Grid Question 1',
   gridheader : [
          {header : 'header1'},
          {header : 'header2'},
          {header : 'header3'}
        ],
   gridrow : [
        {row1 : 'a', row2 : 'b', row3 : 'c'},
        {row1 : 'd', row2 : 'e', row3 : 'f'},
        {row1 : 'g', row2 : 'h', row3 : 'i'}
         ]
}
]
```

Here i want to render a grid using above json. i can iterate through the gridheader and create the table header as follows.

```
{{#omhrs.grid}}
<div>{{question}}</div>
   <table>
     <tr>
    {{#gridheader}}
        <th>{{header}}</th>
    {{/gridheader}}
     </tr>
       </table>
{{/omhrs.grid}}
```

but i am struggling with creating the rest of the data parts. Do you guys have any idea how to achieve this using existing above json structure. Or any better proven way of structuring the json for a grid?

thanks
keth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables are rendered *row* first then *column* so your `gridrow` structure should be really accurately described using `col` instead of `row` (if your data isn't in this order, you need to do some preprocessing work to *transform* your dataset prior to rendering  it to the template):

```
gridrow: [
    { col1: 'a', col2: 'b', col3: 'c' }, 
    { col1: 'd', col2: 'e', col3: 'f' }, 
    { col1: 'g', col2: 'h', col3: 'i' }
]
```

The portion of the template to output the `gridRow` data would be something like this:

```
<tbody>
{{#each gridrow}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{col1}}</td>
        <td>{{col2}}</td>
        <td>{{col3}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
```

See fiddle for fully working code: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/LG5Fp/

**Edit**: If you want to generate dynamic grids:

Data might be (array of arrays):

```
gridrow: [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i']
]
```

Then the template will be:

```
<tbody>
{{#each gridrow}}
    <tr>
        {{#each this}}
            <td>{{this}}</td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
```

The `this` is a special keyword that referes to the current item in the array that it's iterating through.

Comment: thanx for the reply..yeah its really helps....is there any way that we can find a way to render a grid with dynamic number of columns..this above solution we need to know the number columns and column names...is there any other way of doing this for dynamic grids

Comment: @sweetamylase - perfect as always.I'm following you and your answers for about 12 days.and you are so active and although nobody vote lots of your true answers still your score is perfect.I just love to be like you.(-:

Comment: Seems like the include for Handlebars.js was not working, it has been fixed now :) Thanks for letting me know.